# Filter two arrays of objects with different length

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, filter, iteration

I am trying to use JavaScript to filter two arrays of objects with different length, but the result was unsuccessful.  Please help me if you see this post :)

Two arrays of objects are as follows, notice the length of `productList` would always be larger or equal to `shoppingCart`.

I'd like to filter out the objects with the same sizes and colors. I'm wondering if I need to loop through two arrays of objects before actually filtering.

First List- `productList`

```
let productList= [
    {
        "color_code": "DDFFBB",
        "size": "S",
        "stock": 3
    },
    {
        "color_code": "DDFFBB",
        "size": "M",
        "stock": 5
    },
    {
        "color_code": "CCCCCC",
        "size": "S",
        "stock": 4
    },
    {
        "color_code": "CCCCCC",
        "size": "M",
        "stock": 1
    },
    {
        "color_code": "BB7744",
        "size": "S",
        "stock": 2
    },
    {
        "color_code": "BB7744",
        "size": "M",
        "stock": 6
    }
]
```

Second list

```
let shoppingCart=[
    {
        "id": 201807202150,
        "color": "DDFFBB",
        "size": "M",
    },
    {
        "id": 201807202150,
        "color": "BB7744",
        "size": "M",
    },
    {
        "id": 201807202150,
        "color": "DDFFBB",
        "size": "S",
    }
]
```

Expected output

```
 {
        "color_code": "DDFFBB",
        "size": "S",
        "stock": 3
    },
{
        "color_code": "DDFFBB",
        "size": "M",
        "stock": 5
    },
 {
        "color_code": "BB7744",
        "size": "M",
        "stock": 6
    }
```

Thanks for your help!!! You will save my day from infinite errors.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) methods to filter the list.

We filter `productList` with a filter that checks to see whether there is some item in the shopping cart that matches it.

```js
let productList= [
    {
        "color_code": "DDFFBB",
        "size": "S",
        "stock": 3
    },
    {
        "color_code": "DDFFBB",
        "size": "M",
        "stock": 5
    },
    {
        "color_code": "CCCCCC",
        "size": "S",
        "stock": 4
    },
    {
        "color_code": "CCCCCC",
        "size": "M",
        "stock": 1
    },
    {
        "color_code": "BB7744",
        "size": "S",
        "stock": 2
    },
    {
        "color_code": "BB7744",
        "size": "M",
        "stock": 6
    }
];

let shoppingCart=[
    {
        "id": 201807202150,
        "color": "DDFFBB",
        "size": "M",
    },
    {
        "id": 201807202150,
        "color": "BB7744",
        "size": "M",
    },
    {
        "id": 201807202150,
        "color": "DDFFBB",
        "size": "S",
    }
]

const result = productList.filter(
  (product) => shoppingCart.some(
    (item) => item.color == product.color_code && item.size == product.size
  )
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map every element of `shoppingCart` with the corresponding in `productList` like that:

```
const result = shoppingCart.map((e) => productList.find((element) => element.size == e.size && element.color_code === e.color));
```

And if you want to remove the duplicate you just have to do:

```
const unique = new Set(result);
```

This is the output I have:

```
[
   {
      "color_code":"DDFFBB",
      "size":"M",
      "stock":5
   },
   {
      "color_code":"BB7744",
      "size":"M",
      "stock":6
   },
   {
      "color_code":"DDFFBB",
      "size":"S",
      "stock":3
   }
]
```

Comment: _"I'd like to filter out the object with same size and color."_

Comment: You should try, the output is what you want

Comment: a) I'm not OP ;) b) it works in this case because all elements in the _"second list"_ are also in the _"productList"_. The _"I'd like to filter out..."_ suggests that this is not always the case.

Comment: Thanks, that's the output! Thanks everyone for such an instant reply! As a rookie developer I feel some love in this community!!! .some!

Answer (score 1):

You could try this solution:

```js
const productList = [
  { color_code: 'DDFFBB', size: 'S', stock: 3 },
  { color_code: 'DDFFBB', size: 'M', stock: 5 },
  { color_code: 'CCCCCC', size: 'S', stock: 4 },
  { color_code: 'CCCCCC', size: 'M', stock: 1 },
  { color_code: 'BB7744', size: 'S', stock: 2 },
  { color_code: 'BB7744', size: 'M', stock: 6 }
];

const shoppingCart = [
  { id: 201807202150, color: 'DDFFBB', size: 'M' },
  { id: 201807202150, color: 'BB7744', size: 'M' },
  { id: 201807202150, color: 'DDFFBB', size: 'S' }
];

/**
 * Iterate through the productList and find the product that matches the shoppingCart item.
 *
 * @param {object[]} productList
 * @param {object[]} shoppingCart
 * @returns
 */
const getProductStock = (productList, shoppingCart) => {
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < shoppingCart.length; i++) {
    const product = productList.find(item => item.color_code === shoppingCart[i].color && item.size === shoppingCart[i].size);
    result.push(product);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(getProductStock(productList, shoppingCart));
```

**Output**

```js
[
  { color_code: 'DDFFBB', size: 'M', stock: 5 },
  { color_code: 'BB7744', size: 'M', stock: 6 },
  { color_code: 'DDFFBB', size: 'S', stock: 3 }
]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! Another cool method to learn from.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```js
const filterProducts = (products, cart) =>
  products.filter(({
    color_code,
    size
  }) => cart.some(c => c.color === color_code && c.size === size))

let productList = [{
    "color_code": "DDFFBB",
    "size": "S",
    "stock": 3
  },
  {
    "color_code": "DDFFBB",
    "size": "M",
    "stock": 5
  },
  {
    "color_code": "CCCCCC",
    "size": "S",
    "stock": 4
  },
  {
    "color_code": "CCCCCC",
    "size": "M",
    "stock": 1
  },
  {
    "color_code": "BB7744",
    "size": "S",
    "stock": 2
  },
  {
    "color_code": "BB7744",
    "size": "M",
    "stock": 6
  }
]

let shoppingCart = [{
    "id": 201807202150,
    "color": "DDFFBB",
    "size": "M",
  },
  {
    "id": 201807202150,
    "color": "BB7744",
    "size": "M",
  },
  {
    "id": 201807202150,
    "color": "DDFFBB",
    "size": "S",
  }
]

const result = filterProducts(productList, shoppingCart)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the .some function, will sure and check that out!